# Hazelcast Embedded Topology | Latency increases with number of nodes in cluster

Tags: hazelcast

We are running a 5 node cluster of Hazelcast in Embedded mode.
We are running a simple use case of locking using Hazelcast IMap APi.

However, the latency of request flow increases linearly 
with addition of nodes.Is this expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the data structure, but in general "yes".

For [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) the data is spread across the available nodes.

If you have a 3 node cluster, you have the primary copy of 1/3 of the data locally. If you are accessing randomly, then you'll find 66.66% of the calls need to go to other nodes, so will see the impact of the network.

If you expand this to a 5 node cluster, then you have primary copy of 1/5 of the data locally. For the same random access, now it's 80% of the calls involve the network.

As the number of nodes goes up, the benefits of data locality in embedded mode reduce.

Note also this is for random access, if you frequently access the same key you could be lucky and it's local or unlucky and it's remote.

Comment: would adding nodes as Lite Members help to keep the access time constant? Having data only on 2 -3 nodes?

Comment: I doubt it. Access from those nodes would always be remote, so for them consistent. But for others, the network may be involved so inconsistent. Plus the memory footprint across nodes would be inconsistent, some have data some don't.

Comment: Thank you Neil.One more question, if I make my keys PartitionAware, so as to map to the partitions owned by the same node, will that help mitigating the randomization.What I mean is let us say each node is setup with 1 backup node, each node is owner of few partitions, if somehow I indicate to keys being processed by a node to be PartitionAware and map only to partitions owned by a given node.then the time would not increase linearly since the master of the partition would be the same node of the process.The scaling challlenges may be mitigated then?

Comment: This should be a separate question, it's unrelated to the original

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Done.Moved it to other question.